# Is template resolution in c++ possible with a user defined cast?

Tags: c++, templates

Having problems putting my problem into one title I hope someone is able to help me. My problem is specific to C++ templates and I couldn't find anybody having the same problem (or a solution) till now.

Basically I wrote a matrix class and it's working. I used templates to determine the type of the elements and the size of the matrix, so the size is compile time constant and I don't need to use the heap.
When I multiply a matrix with another one, I can use tamplates to determine the dimensions of the resulting matrix. Even that seems to work.

Now I am writing a Vector class. The best way (I thought) is to reuse the matrix code. So in my case Vector<T,S> is simply inheriting from Matrix<T,S,1> (a matrix with the width of the vector and a height of 1). The problem is now the multiplication of a matrix with a vector or a vector with a vector. To solve this problem I created a user defined cast from Vector<T,S> to Matrix<T,1,S> (attention, height and width changed). The compiler is unable to resolve this problem when I am multiplying a vector with another one.

To clarify all this I wrote a little abstraction so you, dear reader, don't have to go through my hole code:

We have two classes:

```
template<int x, int y>
class Base;

template<int s>
class Child;
```

Basically Child is inheriting from Base (Base is the Matrix class and Child is the Vector class).

```
template<int X, int Y>
class Base
{
public:

    template <int X2>
    Base<X2, Y> operator * (const Base<X2, X> &multiplier)
    {
        return Base<X2, Y>();
    }
};
```

The * operator is basically the matrix multiplication part (here doing nothing as you see). Since the height of the multiplier matrix must have the same value as the width of the multiplicant matrix everything is fine and I can only do valid matrix multiplication.

```
template<int S>
class Child : public Base<S, 1>
{
public:
    operator Base<1, S>& ()
    {
        return *reinterpret_cast<Base<1, S>*>(this);
    }
};
```

This is the vector class with a cast operator to allow not only a Vector * Matrix operation but also a Matrix * Vector operation and since Vector is a Matrix itself even Vector * Vector would be possible (at least in theory).
The problem is that there is a compiler error as soon as I try to multiply. For example this code won't work.

```
int main()
{
    Child<3> c1, c2;
    c1 * c2;
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler seems not to be able to do a template resolution. When compiling with gcc I even saw he tries to cast the 2nd Vector to a Matrix, but then he says that X2 wouldn't be defined (although it is, since there is just one special type of cast for a Vector).

**So why is this not possible?**
And if it is not, what would be the best way to do it?

Please don't tell me I shouldn't cast like this. This class will always be standard_layout type so this is standard conform and the most efficient way to perform the cast.
But any serious investigation into this problem are welcome!
As I said I tried everything to solve/understand this problem before I ask a question here.

Comment: Template parameter deduction does not consider user-defined conversions. `c2` could stand for `Base<3, 1>` (derived-to-base conversion), but not for `Base<1, 3>` via a user-defined conversion. Besides, your `reinterpret_cast` approach would lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Since `*` is a template, no user-defined argument conversions are considered.

Comment: You can try not to create types for vectors, but just alias them to corresponding Matrix: `template <typename T, int S> using RowVector = Matrix<T, S, 1>; template <typename T, int H> using ColumnVector = Matrix<T, 1, H>;` Or, you can read about `CRTP` and try to use it.

Comment: Your proposed vector-matrix interface is algebraically problematic, regardless of whether it works in C++ ir not. `Matrix<T,1,N>*Matrix<T,N,1>` is very different from `Matrix<T,N,1>*Matrix<T,1,N>`, yet you propose them to be the same as soon as you squint hard enough to see matrices as vectors. Either don't have any implicit conversions, or have two separate row-vector and column-vector classes whuch are implicitly convertible to/from corresponding matrices but not to each other.

Comment: Igor Tandetnik: So either you did not read properly or you are disagreeing and see  an error within my thoughts. In this case it would be nice if you tell why this reinterpret_cast approach leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: @n.m.: Well for two Vectors that is true. As true as a scalar is not a N * N Matrix, given that N is not 1 (but that is the reason for using a vector). So thank you for your comment.
While this is true for multiplying to vectors, it is just partially true for Matrix*Vector or Vector*Matrix since just one approach (interpret as row or column vector) is possible as long as N!=1.

Nevertheless thank you very much for pointing this out and thank you for the explanation that user defined conversions are not considered for template resolution.

Comment: I don't understand. `Matrix<1,N>` is a row-vector, `Matrix<N,1>` is a column-vector, `Matrix<1,1>` is a scalar. Is there any other way to look at it?

Comment: No Not really you are perfectly right. At least for me.  So as I said: thank you very much! :)